Macro not working in newcommand, but plain text input works
I have three functions to extract day, month, and year from a date string.
Here's the year one.
\makeatletter

\newcommand\extractYearFromDate[1]{\@yearFromDate#1 \@nil}%
\newcommand\@yearFromDate{}%
\newcommand\@removeRightHyphen{}%
\def\@yearFromDate#1 #2\@nil{\@removeRightHyphen#1\@nil}%
\def\@removeRightHyphen#1-#2\@nil{#1}

\makeatother


And this works fine.
\extractYearFromDate{2024-01-02}

Will print 2024. The problem is when I try to use a macro.
\def\myDate{2024-01-02}
\extractYearFromDate{\myDate}

With this I get
\myDate \@nil  
! Paragraph ended before \@removeRightHyphen was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 

Any help here?
The environment I am working in extremely limits the use of external packages. Any plain-latex fix would be greatly appreciated.

\newcommand\extractYearFromDate[1]{\expanded{\noexpand\@yearFromDate#1} \@nil}%

A gentleman and a scholar. Much appreciated.

You can force pre-expansion of the argument via
\newcommand\extractYearFromDate[1]{\expanded{\noexpand\@yearFromDate#1} \@nil}%


No package.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\extract}{mm}{%
  % #1 = year or month or day, #2 = date
  \maguire_extract:ee { \str_foldcase:n {#1} } {#2}
}

\cs_new:Nn \maguire_extract:nn
 {
  \use:e
   {
    \str_case:nn {#1}
     {
      {year}{ \exp_not:n {\use_i:nnn} }
      {month}{ \exp_not:n {\use_ii:nnn} }
      {day}{ \exp_not:n {\use_iii:nnn} }
     }
    \__maguire_extract:w #2 \q_stop
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \maguire_extract:nn {ee}

\cs_new:Npn \__maguire_extract:w #1-#2-#3 \q_stop { {#1}{#2}{#3} }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\extract{year}{2024-01-02}\qquad \extract{Month}{2024-01-02} \qquad \extract{dAY}{2024-01-02}

\newcommand{\mydate}{2024-01-02}

\extract{year}{\mydate}\qquad \extract{Month}{\mydate} \qquad \extract{dAY}{\mydate}

\end{document}

The first argument to \extract is one of year, month or day (whatever capitalization).
The idea is to use the string in the first argument to select the relevant part of the date; the parts are separated with the auxiliary macro with delimited argument.

If you don't want padding zeros, just change the auxiliary function to
\cs_new:Npn \__maguire_extract:w #1-#2-#3 \q_stop { {#1}{\int_eval:n{#2}}{\int_eval:n{#3}} }


The macro \extract can be used in any context where an integer is expected. If you add
\ifnum\extract{day}{\mydate}>2 GREATER\else NOT GREATER\fi

to the code above, you'll get “NOT GREATER”.
We can use the infrastructure to compare dates:
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\isotoday}{}
 {
  \int_eval:n { \c_sys_year_int }
  -
  \int_eval:n { \c_sys_month_int }
  -
  \int_eval:n { \c_sys_day_int }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\extract}{mm}{%
  % #1 = year or month or day, #2 = date
  \maguire_extract:ee { \str_foldcase:n {#1} } {#2}
}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\comparedates}{mmmm}
 {
  \maguire_compare:eenn {#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}
 }

\cs_new:Nn \maguire_extract:nn
 {
  \use:e
   {
    \str_case:nn {#1}
     {
      {year}{ \exp_not:n {\use_i:nnn} }
      {month}{ \exp_not:n {\use_ii:nnn} }
      {day}{ \exp_not:n {\use_iii:nnn} }
     }
    \__maguire_extract:w #2 \q_stop
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \maguire_extract:nn {ee}

\cs_new:Npn \__maguire_extract:w #1-#2-#3 \q_stop { {#1}{#2}{#3} }

\cs_new:Nn \maguire_compare:nnnn
 {
  \bool_if:nTF
   {
    \int_compare_p:n { \maguire_extract:ee {year}{#1} > \maguire_extract:ee {year}{#2} }
    ||
    \int_compare_p:n { \maguire_extract:ee {month}{#1} > \maguire_extract:ee {month}{#2} }
    ||
    \int_compare_p:n { \maguire_extract:ee {day}{#1} > \maguire_extract:ee {day}{#2} }
   }
   {#3}{#4}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \maguire_compare:nnnn {ee}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\extract{year}{2024-01-02}\qquad \extract{Month}{2024-01-02} \qquad \extract{dAY}{2024-01-02}

\newcommand{\mydate}{2024-01-02}

\extract{year}{\mydate}\qquad \extract{Month}{\mydate} \qquad \extract{dAY}{\mydate}

\ifnum\extract{day}{\mydate}>2 GREATER\else NOT GREATER\fi

\comparedates{2024-02-02}{\mydate}{LATER}{NOT LATER}

\comparedates{\mydate}{\isotoday}{LATER}{NOT LATER}

\end{document}



Would this work with conditional compiling via ifnum? The idea is to check a date, and have one thing printed if it is before year-month-day, and another thing if after.

@RyanMaguire Yes, see the additional comment.

Excellent, that's quite a nice universal function for this task. Thanks!

@RyanMaguire I added the code for comparing two dates.

That is extremely helpful! Before you go, would \today work as the second input in comparedates?

@RyanMaguire No, because it doesn't expand to a date in ISO format. You may want to check with datetime2 for that.

Alrighty, thanks!

@RyanMaguire I changed the final code adding an \isotoday macro that can be used in the context of \comparedates.

@david-carlisle and @egreg provided excellent answers.
The intent is for this to work with plasTeX and latex2edx, which are LaTeX to HTML compilers written in Python. Quite unfortunately, these tools do not support the full LaTeX language. In particular, they do not support \expanded, \noexpand, \ExplSyntaxOn, and several other commands. They do support\expandafter so I rewrote everything to use that.
If anyone else falls into the (small) niche of using plasTeX or latex2edx for their courses, the following worked (albeit with a few warnings on the latex2edx side. pdflatex does not complain).
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
%                               Begin User Input                               %
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------%

\def\releaseTime{T15:00}
\def\dueTime{T20:00}

\def\firstUnitReleaseDate{2024-09-04}
\def\firstUnitOriginalDate{2024-09-18}
\def\firstUnitExtensionDate{2024-09-25}

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
%                                End User Input                                %
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
\documentclass{article}

\def\asTwoDigitNumber#1{\ifnum#1<10 0\fi\the#1}
\def\isoToday{\the\year-\asTwoDigitNumber\month-\asTwoDigitNumber\day}

\makeatletter

\newcommand\extractYearFromDate[1]{\@yearFromDate#1 \@nil}%
\newcommand\@yearFromDate{}%
\newcommand\@removeRightHyphen{}%
\def\@yearFromDate#1 #2\@nil{\@removeRightHyphen#1\@nil}%
\def\@removeRightHyphen#1-#2\@nil{#1}

\newcommand\extractMonthFromDate[1]{\@monthFromDate#1 \@nil}%
\newcommand\@monthFromDate{}%
\newcommand\@removeBothHyphens{}%
\def\@monthFromDate#1 #2\@nil{\@removeBothHyphens#1\@nil}%
\def\@removeBothHyphens#1-#2-#3\@nil{#2}

\newcommand\extractDayFromDate[1]{\@dayFromDate#1 \@nil}%
\newcommand\@dayFromDate{}%
\newcommand\@removeLeftHyphen{}%
\def\@dayFromDate#1 #2\@nil{\@removeLeftHyphen#1\@nil}%
\def\@removeLeftHyphen#1-#2-#3\@nil{#3}

\makeatother

\def\yearFromDate#1{\expandafter\extractYearFromDate\expandafter{#1}}
\def\monthFromDate#1{\expandafter\extractMonthFromDate\expandafter{#1}}
\def\dayFromDate#1{\expandafter\extractDayFromDate\expandafter{#1}}

\def\compareDates#1#2#3#4{%
    \ifnum\yearFromDate{#1}=\yearFromDate{#2}
        \ifnum\monthFromDate{#1}=\monthFromDate{#2}
            \ifnum\dayFromDate{#1}<\dayFromDate{#2}
                #3
            \else
                #4
            \fi
        \else
            \ifnum\monthFromDate{#1}<\monthFromDate{#2}
                #3
            \else
                #4
            \fi
        \fi
    \else
        \ifnum\yearFromDate{#1}<\yearFromDate{#2}
            #3
        \else
            #4
        \fi
    \fi
}

\def\unitOneReleaseDate{"\firstUnitReleaseDate\releaseTime"}
\def\unitOneDueDate{%
    \compareDates{\isoToday}{\firstUnitOriginalDate}%
    {%
        "\firstUnitOriginalDate\dueTime"
    }%
    {%
        "\firstUnitExtensionDate\dueTime"
    }%
}

\title{Automate Dates Test}
\author{Ryan Maguire}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    The due date XML attribute is
    due=\unitOneDueDate
\end{document}

This creates the following.


Not idea if datetime2 work with plasTeX, but for normal PDF outputs you can do something like \documentclass{article} \usepackage{datetime2} \begin{document} \DTMsavedate{mydate}{2024-12-31} \DTMusedate{mydate} The day  \DTMfetchday{mydate} of month \DTMfetchmonth{mydate} witll end \DTMfetchyear{mydate}.  \end{document}

I tried this (another tex.stackexchange post suggested it), and unfortunately it didn't work. The environment is a bit limiting. Fortunately many of the main packages (ams related) used for typesetting math are fully supported. The other annoyance is tikz and asymptote aren't supported, so we write our figures in standalone asymptote code, compile down to SVG, and then include this into the tex source (latex2edx can handle inline XML and inline HTML, which is neat).
